# How to read json file using filebeat and send it to elasticsearch via logstash

Tags: json, filebeat, elk

This is my json log file. I'm trying to store the file to my elastic-Search through my logstash.

```
{"message":"IM: Orchestration","level":"info"}
{"message":"Investment Management","level":"info"}
```

Here is my filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
   - D:/Development_Avecto/test-log/tn-logs/im.log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
processors:
 - decode_json_fields:
     fields: ["message"]
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

```
input{
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

filter {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }   
}   

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "data"
    }
}
```

No able to view out put in elasticserach. Not able to find whats the error.
filebeat log

```
2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:134  Loading registrar data from D:\Development_Avecto\filebeat-6.6.2-windows-x86_64\data\registry
2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530    INFO    registrar/registrar.go:141  States Loaded from registrar: 10 
2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530    WARN    beater/filebeat.go:367  Filebeat is unable to load the Ingest Node pipelines for the configured modules because the Elasticsearch output is not configured/enabled. If you have already loaded the Ingest Node pipelines or are using Logstash pipelines, you can ignore this warning. 
2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:72   Loading Inputs: 1 
2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530    INFO    log/input.go:138    Configured paths: [D:\Development_Avecto\test-log\tn-logs\im.log] 2019-06-18T11:30:03.448+0530  INFO    input/input.go:114  Starting input of type: log; ID: 16965758110699470044  
2019-06-18T11:30:03.449+0530    INFO    crawler/crawler.go:106  Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1 
2019-06-18T11:30:34.842+0530    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":312,"time":{"ms":312}},"total":{"ticks":390,"time":{"ms":390},"value":390},"user":{"ticks":78,"time":{"ms":78}}},"handles":{"open":213},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"66983518-39e6-461c-886d-a1f99da6631d","uptime":{"ms":30522}},"memstats":{"gc_next":4194304,"memory_alloc":2963720,"memory_total":4359488,"rss":22421504}},"filebeat":{"events":{"added":1,"done":1},"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0}},"output":{"type":"logstash"},"pipeline":{"clients":1,"events":{"active":0,"filtered":1,"total":1}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":10,"update":1},"writes":{"success":1,"total":1}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":4}}}}} 2
```

Comment: Are you running all services on same machine ? Also check for the logstash and elasticsearch logs for any error.

Comment: Hi sir,
Yes, running all services on same machine. In both elasticsearch and logstash i dont see any error.
When i connect directly to elasticsearch im able to view the data in elastic.
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - D:/Development_Avecto/test-log/tLog-file.log
  input_type: log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
processors:
- drop_fields:
    fields: ['beat.hostname']
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
  index: "data"

Comment: Same when i try to connect with logstash below code its not working and no errors are displaying in log.
input{
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

filter {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }   
}   

output{
    elasticsearch{
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "data"
    }
}

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 5):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/dotnet/master/setup.html

Check step 3 at the bottom of the page for the config you need to put in your filebeat.yaml file:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths: /path/to/logs.json
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.overwrite_keys: true
  json.add_error_key: true
  json.expand_keys: true
```

Comment: Hey, I thank you sooo much for this!!! I tried to get this to work days long. With your help, it just works... so great. Yes, and I can read docs... it was a bit unclear what else I would need. It actually needs this lines... great! You have a coffee for free (https://www.helloguest-solutions.com/de/index.html)

Comment: Everyone... this a solution to injest filebeat json logs into elastic search directly. I don't need logstash.